# Analysing Stability of a Pair of Coupled Second Order Nonlinear ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, jacobian

I have the below pair of coupled non-linear second-order ODEs for $x$ and $y$ and wish to analyse the stability of the system.

$\gamma_1 \dot{x} - \gamma_2 ( \dot{x} - \dot{y} ) = (m_1 + m_2) d^2 \ddot{x} + I \ddot{x} + m_2 d^2 \ddot{y} + d(m_1 + m_2) g  x,$

$\gamma_2 (\dot{x}- \dot{y}) = m_2 d^2 \ddot{y} + I \ddot{y} + m_2 d^2 \ddot{x} + dm_2g y,  $

where $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, $m_1$, $m_2$, $g$, $d$ and $I$ are parameters of the system.

What would be the easiest way to analyse stability?  I have tried to make substitutions $u = \dot{x}$, $v= \dot{y}$ to convert the system into four first order ODEs, but I cannot write it in the form

$\begin{align}
    y &= \begin{bmatrix}
          \dot{u} \\
           \dot{v}
         \end{bmatrix} = \textbf{A}  \begin{bmatrix}
          u \\
           v
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}$,

where $\textbf{A} $ is the Jacobian, because $\dot{u}$ and $\dot{v}$ have coefficients which cannot be removed by dividing through, can someone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reduce it to the form

$$
\dot X = f(X)
$$

with $X = (x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)^{\dagger}$

After that, verify the equilibrium set by solving $X_0 = \arg\{ f(X) = 0\}$ following with the  analysis of $J(X_0) = \nabla_X f(X_0)$ eigenvalues.

NOTE

Calling $x=x_1, \dot x_1 = x_2, y = y_1, \dot y_1 = y_2$ and solving for $\dot x_1, \dot x_2,\dot y_1, \dot y_2$ we arrive at

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot x_1 &=& x_2\\
\dot x_2 &=& \frac{d^3 g m_2^2 y_1-d g x_1 (m_1+m_2) \left(d^2 m_2+I\right)-\gamma_2 x_2 \left(2 d^2m_2+I\right)+\gamma_2 y_2 \left(2 d^2 m_2+I\right)}{d^4 m_1 m_2-\gamma_1 \left(d^2m_2+I\right)+d^2 I (m_1+2 m_2)+I^2}\\
\dot y_1 &=& y_2\\
\dot y_2 &=& \frac{d^3 g m_2 x_1 (m_1+m_2)-d g m_2 \text{y1} \left(d^2 (m_1+m_2)-\gamma_1+I\right)+\gamma_2 x_2\left(d^2 (m_1+2 m_2)-\gamma_1+I\right)-\gamma_2 y_2 \left(d^2 (m_1+2 m_2)-\gamma_1+I\right)}{d^4m_1 m_2-\gamma_1 \left(d^2 m_2+I\right)+d^2 I (m_1+2 m_2)+I^2}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: What do you mean with $\dot X = f(X)$, with $X = (x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)^{\dagger}$, could you give an example?

Comment: Please. See attached note.

Comment: If you calculate the Jacobian matrix for the corresponding system of 4 first order equations, it seems to have only constant entries (since $x_1$, $x_2$, $y_1$ or $y_2$ either vanish or become 1 after differentiating), is that a problem ie. the Jacobian will be the same whatever the equilibrium points $X_0$?

Comment: The system is linear and the equilibrium point is at $x_1=x_2=y_1=y_2 = 0$.

Comment: Don't you need to evaluate the Jacobian and then substitute in the value for the equilibrium point?  But in this case the Jacobian is a constant matrix.  Or do you mean that the point at $0$ is automatically stable?

Comment: Within the eigenvalues method, the stability depends on the eigenvalues found. See for instance this link: https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Industrial_and_Systems_Engineering/Book%3A_Chemical_Process_Dynamics_and_Controls_(Woolf)/10%3A_Dynamical_Systems_Analysis/10.04%3A_Using_eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_to_find_stability_and_solve_ODEs

Comment: I was just wondering as when I evaluate the eigenvalues of the Jacobian for certain values of the parameters, if I sufficiently increase the parameters $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ corresponding to damping, an eigenvalue with positive real part appears which indicates an instability, which doesn't seem to make sense.